# Referencing a ColdFusion variable in html

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Is it possible to reference a cf variable in html?
Example:

```
<cfset  langValue ="uk">

<html lang="#langValue#">
```

In this way does not work, however if I then print it out with cf tags it obviously works:

```
<cfoutput> #langValue# </cfoutput>
```

Any how to reference the `langValue` variable in the html `lang` tag?

Comment: FWIW, it has nothing to do with html :) If you want that variable to be evaluated, you must wrap it use `cfoutput`, as mentioned below. Otherwise, CF ignores it and returns the exact text you entered "as is". Pound signs and all.

Comment: Did you even search for how to output ColdFusion variables?

Comment: This may be useful: http://learncfinaweek.com/

Comment: @ScottStroz yes otherwise I would not know <cfoutput> #langValue# </cfoutput> which I posted in my question

Comment: @duncan thanks for the link, it seems a very valualbe resource for learning cf!

Comment: The CF server is only interested in CF tags, functions and expressions. Any text that is *not* CF code is ignored. So from the server's perspective, there is no difference between: `<cfoutput> #langValue# </cfoutput>` and `<cfoutput> <html lang="#langValue#"></cfoutput>`.

Comment: Also, `<html lang="<cfoutput>#langValue#</cfoutput>">` is valid, (though generally more difficult to read).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to make sure to wrap your HTML in the `cfoutput` :

```
<cfoutput>
    <html lang="#langValue#">
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't use cfset any longer.
The new hotness is:

```
<cfscript>
langValue = 'uk'
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
<html lang="#langValue#">
</html>
</cfoutput>
```